# kendo chart categoryAxis

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I`m beginner using kendo stacked chart.

this is my categoryAxis.

```
            categoryAxis: {
            categories: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: true
            },
            visible: true
        },
        chartArea: {
            height : 200
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #",
            color: "white"
        }
```

but, 0 index tooltip shows 'd'.
what is the problem ?

[tooltip image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfcGk.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your image you are using a shared tooltip, so try defining your tooltip like this:

```
tooltip: {
      visible: true,
      sharedTemplate: "<div>#: category #</div> # for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { # <div>#: points[i].series.name# : #: points[i].value #</div> # } #",
      color: "white",
      shared: true
  }
```